# Set the value for <select> without using 'v-model'

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I would like to have something like the following Vue template, but it does not work with the property `selectedVal`. What is the correct property name?

```
<select :selectedVal="myList" multiple>
  <option value="abc">ABC</option>
</select>
```

For `<input>` the prop to bind is `value`, but for `<select>` it does not seem to be documented anywhere. I am looking for the name of the correct prop to bind.

Comment: do you want to generate option tag via v-for, or it is fixed?

Comment: btw, I think `selected` is an attribute in option tag, not in select tag.

Comment: @choasia: My options are generated using a v-for.

Comment: is it what you need: https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/pncrudf8/ ?

Comment: It may work, but it is not what I want to know.

Comment: So you mean why `<input :value="inputVal" />` works but `<select 
 :selected="myList" multiple>...</select>` doesn't?

Comment: I am looking for the name of the correct prop to bind.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*I answered because it's difficult to quote code snippet in a comment.*

I think you asked this question after looking into the document [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select), which showed an elegant way to define selected items.

```
<select v-model="selected">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
```

Actually, I doubt if there's a v-bind prop performs like this because [`value` is an attribute of `input` and `option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input), but [`selected` is not an attribute of `select` but an attribute of `option`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select) and I can't find any alternatives in `select`.

Also, after browsing the source code of Vue.js, I didn't see vue did much for binding an attribute (code [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/e3c578814bed891d3818d7306cca24116d980b3f/src/compiler/parser/index.js#L451) and [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/dev/src/compiler/helpers.js#L22-L24)) rather than pushing values of `v-bind` into the element's `attrs` list.

```
export function addAttr (el: ASTElement, name: string, value: string) {
  (el.attrs || (el.attrs = [])).push({ name, value })
}
```

On the other hand, `select` seems to be an special case in v-model (see code [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/master/src/platforms/web/runtime/directives/model.js#L69-L102)).
So, I provided [the solution](https://jsfiddle.net/choasia/pncrudf8) in the comment by binding `selected` to option instead of `select`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @Vincent Not at all.